# how to send numbers with UDP in Linux with C++

Tags: sockets

I would like to send messages with UDP protocol. The data in the message is 6 numbers, say from 0x01 to 0x06. All the examples I found online only send strings. Can anyone tell me how to make a message with numbers to send by UDP? Thanks. By the way, what I want is something like socketCAN. In each data frame, I have 8 bytes to write data (where I can write a number).

Comment: *All the examples I found online only send strings* Where?

Comment: @texasbruce just google udp linux c++, I can see many results.

Comment: Take a look at some of the *core* UDP protocols , such as {BOOTP, DNS,NTP} These basically exchange numbers with barely any strings involved. And C++ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ASCII values of the numbers you want to send. When you use UDP, You are always sending strings of bytes, and numbers have an ASCII representation.

If you want to send the numbers from 1 to 5, the packet need to have the following format:

```
const u_char TIMESTAMP[] =     {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35};
```

Those are the numbers in hexadecimal notation that represent the numbers from 1 to 5. You should note that it must be an unsigned data type so you can prevent overflowing the data to their respective negative values. That could produce unintended behaviour

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mind giving a simple example?

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: Glad I helped. Check the site for more info about other Protocols and related topics.

Comment: Hi Kolt. I got another problem about this. For a 8-bit Hex number, the largest is 0xFF. However, if I use this input, I got an error  narrowing conversion of '255' from 'int' to 'char' inside {}; I wonder is there a way that I can  add a number larger than 0x7F? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you used codetags. I can't figure it out like this.